# Reconstructing a flying object's 3D trajectory off a single 2D-video

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, homography

[image]

I am trying to reconstruct the basketball's 3D trajectory, using solely the broadcast feed.
To do this, I had to calculate the homography matrix, so in each frame I successfully tracked the ball, and 6 points which their location is known in the "real world" (4 on the court itself, and 2 on the backboard) as seen in the picture.

Using the laws of physics I've also approximated the z-coordinate of the ball in every frame.

Now I want to map the ball's location from the 2D pixel coordinates to the real world. The code I have right now(which is attached later), inputs the pixel location (u,v) and height (z) and outputs x,y,z location. It works well for points on the court (meaning z=0), however when I need to track something in the air (the ball), the results don't make sense. If anyone can help tell me what I need to do to get the mapping I would appreciate it a lot.

```
# Make empty list for ball's 3D location
ball_3d_location = []
# Fixed things 
size         = frame_list[0].shape
focal_length = size[1]
center       = (size[1]/2, size[0]/2)
camera_matrix= np.array(
                         [[focal_length, 0, center[0]],
                         [0, focal_length, center[1]],
                         [0, 0, 1]], dtype = "double"
                         )
def groundProjectPoint(image_point, z = 0.0):
    camMat = np.asarray(camera_matrix)
    iRot   = np.linalg.inv(rotMat)
    iCam   = np.linalg.inv(camMat)
uvPoint = np.ones((3, 1))

# Image point
uvPoint[0, 0] = image_point[0]
uvPoint[1, 0] = image_point[1]

tempMat = np.matmul(np.matmul(iRot, iCam), uvPoint)
tempMat2 = np.matmul(iRot, translation_vector)

s = (z + tempMat2[2, 0]) / tempMat[2, 0]
wcPoint = np.matmul(iRot, (np.matmul(s * iCam, uvPoint) - translation_vector))

# wcPoint[2] will not be exactly equal to z, but very close to it
assert int(abs(wcPoint[2] - z) * (10 ** 8)) == 0
wcPoint[2] = z

return wcPoint
dist_coeffs = np.zeros((4,1)) # Assuming no lens distortion

# The tracked points coordinates in the "Real World"
model_points = np.array([
(0,1524/2,0),         #Baseline-sideline
(0,-244,0),           #Paint-sideline
(579,-244,0),         #Paint-FT
(579,1524/2,0),       #Sideline-FT
(122,-182.9/2,396.32),#Top Left Backboard
(122,182.9/2,396.32)],dtype=np.float32 #Top Right BackBoard
)
for i,frame in enumerate(bball_frames):
  f             =frame
  #This array has the pixel coordinates of the court & backboard points
  image_points  =np.array([f.baseline_sideline,
  f.paint_sideline,
  f.paint_ft,
  f.sideline_ft,
  f.top_left_backboard,
  f.top_right_backboard],dtype=np.float32)

  (success, rotation_vector, translation_vector) = cv2.solvePnP(model_points, image_points, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)

  rotMat, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vector)
  #We assume we know the ball's height in each frame due to the laws of physics.
  ball_3d_location+=[groundProjectPoint(image_point=ball_2d_location[i],z = ball_height[i])]
```

EDIT: [image: Is this how to calculate the basketball's height?]

Comment: You haven't shown any results, so this is still not a "proper" [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Given the sparse algorithmic comments, I may be missing something you know.  The critical part I don't see is any code that glues the ball's flight path to a vertical plane from the release point to the next contact point on the backboard.  This assumes *no* x-y curve on the ball, but you'll get a close approximation if you do that.

Comment: I assumed that I know the Z-coordinate of the ball at any given frame, if that's what you mean. The function is based on gravity, the shot's release height and the time the ball has spent in the air until landing in the basket

Comment: That's not what I meant.  The arc of the ball is physically restricted to a plane that's perpendicular to the floor, passing through the point of release (shooter's hand) and the point where it contacts the backboard.  Defining that plane and working within it should help you interpret the projection of the ball from 2D to 3D.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...So let's say I can estimate the shooting location on the court (x,y). using the laws of physics I can say where the ball is in each frame (x,y) wise and then from that and the pixel coordinates I can extract the height coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I want to clarify the planes of reference:

1. The video you have is a 2D projection (viewing plane) of the 3D world, as a plane perpendicular to the centerline of the camera lens.
2. The shot arc is embedded in a plane (shot plane) which is perpendicular to the real-world (3D) floor, defined by the point of release (shooter's hand) and point of contact (backboard).

The shot arc you see on the video is from the projection of that shot plane onto the viewing plane.

> I want to make sure we're clear with respect to your most recent
>   comment: So let's say I can estimate the shooting location on the
>   court (x,y). using the laws of physics I can say where the ball is in
>   each frame (x,y) wise and then from that and the pixel coordinates I
>   can extract the height coordinate?

1. You can, indeed, estimate the (x,y) coordinate.  However, I would not ascribe my approach to "the laws of physics".  I would use analytic geometry.
2. You can estimate, with good accuracy, the 3D coordinates of both the release point (from the known (x, y, 0) position of the shooter's feet) and the end point on the backboard (whose corners are known).
3. Drop a perpendicular from each of these points to the floor (z=0).  That line on the floor is the vertical projection of the arc to the floor -- these are the (x,y) coordinates of the ball in flight.
4. For each video frame, drop a projected perpendicular from the ball's image to that line on the floor ... *that* gives you the (x,y) coordinates of the ball, for what it's worth.
5. You have the definition (equation) of the view plane, the viewpoint (camera), and the arc plane.  To determine the ball's position for each video frame, draw a line from the viewpoint, through the ball's image on the view plane.  Determine the intersection of this line with the arc plane.  *That* gives you the 3D coordinates of the ball in that frame.

Does that clarify a useful line of attack?

Comment: Thank you, this is so helpful. The only problem, is that the ball doesn't actually hit the backboard as it goes straight through the basket. But lets say the "shot plane" goes through the mid-point of the backboard (which we know it's real life as well as pixel coordinates) and we can project that point to the floor. Then we draw that line you described in step 3. Do we calculate the height of the basketball in a given frame as shown in the picture that I just edited in the original post?

Comment: You know the exact position of the backboard's upper corners.  From this, and NBA equipment regulations, you can derive the center of the hoop.

Comment: Nice work!  You simplified the projections down to the linear combination needed for the z-coordinate.  Exactly right for that coordinate.  I gave you an over-engineered solution, which may help you with other computations on the video as well.

Comment: Oh I understand what you meant now, so yea the line would be from the middle of the basket's projected point on the court (z=0) to the shooting location, and then we measure the length of the perpendicular from that line to the "top of the backboard" line and then do what is described in the picture. Thank you a lot, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Glad to help.  I know it's hard to visualize all of this at the start; there are so many things happening at once, it can be tricky to simplify things far enough to see the simple, Euclidean, linear geometric relationships you need for each detail.

Comment: We're lucky that your case is amenable to linear simplifications: no worries about a slight lateral curve on the flight arc, or a 3cm y-coordinate adjustment because the shooter releases right-handed, or calculating where in the "made-the-shot" cone the ball actually lands (up to 5cm adjustment), etc.